# sklearn's GradientBoostingRegressor gives the same prediction for different inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I encountered a weird behavior while trying to train sklearn's **GradientBoostingRegressor** and make prediction. I will bring an example to demonstrate the issue on a reduced dataset but issue remains on a larger dataset as well. I have the following 2 small datasets adapted from a big dataset. As you can see the target variable is identical for both cases but input variables are different though their values are close to each other. The target variables(Y) are in the last column.

I have the following code:

```
d1 = {'0':[101869.2,102119.9,102138.0,101958.3,101903.7,12384900],  
        '1':[101809.1,102031.3,102061.7,101930.0,101935.2,11930700],
        '2':[101978.0,102208.9,102209.8,101970.0,101878.6,12116700],
        '3':[101869.2,102119.9,102138.0,101958.3,101903.7,12301200],
        '4':[102125.5,102283.4,102194.0,101884.8,101806.0,10706100],
        '5':[102215.5,102351.9,102214.0,101769.3,101693.6,10116900]}                    
data1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).T
X1 = data1.ix[:,:4]
Y = data1[5]

d2 = {'0':[101876.0,102109.8,102127.6,101937.0,101868.4,12384900],
        '1':[101812.9,102021.2,102058.8,101912.9,101896.4,11930700],
        '2':[101982.5,102198.0,102195.4,101940.2,101842.5,12116700],
        '3':[101876.0,102109.8,102127.6,101937.0,101868.4,12301200],
        '4':[102111.3,102254.8,102182.8,101832.7,101719.7,10706100],
        '5':[102184.6,102320.2,102188.9,101699.9,101548.1,10116900]}
data2 = pd.DataFrame(d2).T
X2 = data2.ix[:,:4]
Y = data2[5]

re1 = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=40,max_depth=None,random_state=1)
re1.fit(X1,Y)
pred1 = re1.predict(X1)

re2 = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=40,max_depth=None,random_state=3)
re2.fit(X2,Y)
pred2 = re2.predict(X2)
```

where 
X1 is a *pandas* DataFrame corresponding to *Column 1* through *Column 5* on the **1st** dataset
X2 is a *pandas* DataFrame corresponding to *Column 1* through *Column 5* on the **2nd** dataset
Y represents the target column.
The issue I am facing is that I cannot explain why **pred1** is exactly the same as **pred2**?? As long as **X1** and **X2** are not the same  **pred1** and **pred2** must also be different, musn't they? Help me to find my false assumption, please.

Answer (score 4):

What you observe is perfectly expected.
You fit a high complexity estimator to the data (max_depth=None), so it is easy to learn all of the data by heart, that is overfit completely on the training data.
Then the prediction will be whatever labels you gave for training.

Have a look at Peter's talk here about how to tune GradientBoosting correctly:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5l3g91NZfQ

Anyhow, you should at least have a test-set.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since you are fitting X1 and X2 to the same Y, it is reasonable that pred1 and pred2 are similar. When your Regressor is very powerful (can fit anything to anything) or your problem is too easy (can be fitted exactly by your regressor), then pred1 and pred2 will be both equal to Y.